# How to make the title label to be fit within the back button of UInavigation controller :XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I'm using navigation controller in one of my apps, and I am troubling with the title of navigation controller back button. I want

**solution 1:** to make the title label to be fit within the back button area (something like:`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES`)

**or**

**solution2:** to make the back button large enough to hold the text.

(solution 1 is more preferable).

For more info, I'm giving an image here...

---

[image]

fig1: Good for short titletext.

fig2: Title get truncated for long text.

fig3: Make the text self adjustable.

fig4: Make the button large enough to hold the text.

---

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: do you use the default navigation bar? or customize

Comment: yes. I'm using the default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IOSX ,till now  apple not providing the permissions for customising the back button in navigation controller ,for achieving your requirement you can use your custom button because we are not having permissions for changing the back button frame.

Answer (score 0):

put below code in you .m file
button will auto resize with title

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Back";//put here your title
}
```

you will be succeed

Comment: NO. When the navigationbar title becomes large, the text again will get trauncated... Any way, thanks for the answer.